# JQuery hashchange event - where to place?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery hashchange event.

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function () {
//do something
});
```

When my url contains a hash during first time load I understand that this needs to be triggered with `$(window).hashchange();`

Can I place it inside document ready instead?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).on('hashchange', function () {
    //do something
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can trigger it manually like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).on('hashchange', function () {
        //do something
    }).trigger('hashchange');
});
```

Or you can do it like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //attaching the event listener
    $(window).on('hashchange', function () {
        //do something
    });

    //manually tiggering it if we have hash part in URL
    if (window.location.hash) {
        $(window).trigger('hashchange')
    }
});
```